# Concatenate a number of columns based on a range in Excel

Tags: excel, concatenation

All,

I am trying to concatenate a range (range 1) in case any cell in the range contains the string "yes" . In case range1 has multiple hits (multiple cells with "yes"; I would like to show all hits within one output cell (best: comma seperated).

So far I tried index and match, but this will only return the first value found. I would like to have all hits within one cell, comma seperated.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(range1;MATCH(Yes"&"*";range1;0));"")
```

Range1 consists of 8 coloumns and one row. Only cells with the word "yes" should be concatenated.

Any idea?

Thanks
Julia

Excel version 2013

Comment: look at the [tag:textjoin] tag.

Comment: i believe textjoin does not work for Excel version 2013.

Comment: you mean like this: | yes | no | yes | maybe | > output > |yes,yes|  ?

Comment: nearly: I mean like: |yes (abc)| no| yes (defg)| yes (zzz)|>output> |yes (abc), yes (defg), yes (zzz)|

Answer (score 1):

With formula I found this:

Using into `CONCATENATE` an `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yes",A2)),A2&", "," ")` for each cell in your range1. It will be something like:

```
=TRIM(CONCATENATE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yes",A2)),A2&", "," "),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yes",B2)),B2&", "," "),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yes",C2)),C2&", "),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yes",D2)),D2&", "," "),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yes",E2)),E2&", "," "),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yes",F2)),F2&", "," "),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yes",G2)),G2&", "," "),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yes",H2)),H2&", "," ")))
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome, please don't forget mark my answer as the answer in your post I am building my reputation :)